# Указатели на элементы вектора в C++

Tags: c++, указатели, vector

Есть указатель на конкретный элемент вектора, после изменения вектора, будет ли указатель указывать на тот же элемент?

Comment: Смотря какого изменения, но в общем случае — нет.

Answer (score 3):

Смотря что подразумевать под изменением вектора. Например, при вставке произошла реаллокация, тогда элементы уже в общем случае будут находиться в другом месте.

Если удалить элемент перед рассматриваемым, то все элементы после удаленного сдвинутся на один элемент, а указатель на рассматриваемый уже не будет на него указывать.

Более подробно следует смотреть вот [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) в разделе Iterator invalidation (нужна информация про *ссылки* на элементы вектора)

Comment: А как сделать указатель на конкретный элемент, чтобы он не менялся?

Comment: @Vikusssya не изменять вектор

Comment: @Vikusssya, вместо указателя храните ссылку/указатель на вектор и индекс элемента внутри вектора.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy При вставке/удалении элемента до рассматриваемого индексы будут невалидными, хотя это спасает от инвалидации указателей на элементы до вставленного/удаленного

Answer (score 0):

Как уже написали, если вектор изменяется, то нужно быть очень аккуратным. Но так как у нас с++, то может лучше под указателем иметь ввиду умные указатели? Тогда все стает заметно лучше.

Если сделать `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>`, то все будет так как нужно. Желающим использовать элементы вектора раздавать `weak_ptr`. В этом случае, если элементы перемещались, то все будет хорошо. Если элемент был удален, то `weak_ptr` об этом узнает (`shared_ptr` даже сохранит элемент). Единственный минус - с индексами будет проблема - то есть, что бы узнать индекс элемента нужно будет пробежаться по массиву и посравнивать, а арифметика указателей работать не будет.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

void print(const std::weak_ptr<int>& el) {
    auto sh = el.lock();
    if (sh) {
        std::cout << *sh << "\n";
    }
    else {
      std::cout << "oops, empty\n";
    }
}

void print(const std::shared_ptr<int>& el) {
    if (el) {
        std::cout << *el << "\n";
    }
    else {
      std::cout << "oops, empty\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> a;

    a.push_back(std::make_shared<int>(1));
    a.push_back(std::make_shared<int>(2));
    a.push_back(std::make_shared<int>(3));

    std::weak_ptr<int> x = a[1];
    std::shared_ptr<int> y = a[2];
    print(x); // выведет 2
    print(y); // выведет 3

    a.erase(a.begin(), a.end());
    print(x); // выведет oops
    print(y); // все ещё 3
}
```